# How to autoreload web-app served by NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, livereload

I was using gulp webserver previously.
Now ReactJS webapp is accessible through nodeJS+express server:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../dist"));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

Nodemon reloads the server.
The `/../dist` folder contains concatenated, transpiled etc. reactJS app.
How do i make reactjs webapp live reloading on source code change?

Comment: You shouldn't change source code in live/production env "on-the-fly", I mean you should do a complete deploy with the new code and then restart the whole app.

Comment: ok, how do i do that without pushing 'cmd+r' each time?

Comment: What build process are you using to transpile your code? If you want the code to update on the fly, checkout https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-module-replacement.

Comment: If you don't care about individual components reloading, check out https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei